# Probability questions about rolling a die four times

Tags: probability

The question says:

> A die is rolled four times.  What is the probability of rolling
>
> a) no 4's on any roll?
>
> b) at least one 4 on any roll?
>
> c) an odd number on each roll?

I'm not sure how to solve this, because the die is rolled four times not just once.

Comment: Hint : every roll of the dice is independant.

Comment: A good place to start would be to calculate the probabilities of not rolling a 4 on a single roll and of rolling an odd number on a single roll.  Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a straight forward question about a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: Notice that the answers to parts a and b must add up to exactly $1$.

Answer (score 2):

(a) The probability of not getting a $4$ on a single dice roll is $5/6$ because there are $5$ desirable outcomes $(1,2,3,5,6)$ out of $6$ total outcomes. Now by independence, the probability of not getting $4$ on *any* of the four roles is just $\boxed{(5/6)^{4}}$.

(b) The probability of getting at least one $4$ on any roll is one minus the probability of getting no $4$'s on any of the four rolls (this is true because if we don't get zero fours, then we must have gotten at least one four). In (a), we computed the probability of getting no $4$'s to get $(5/6)^{4}$, so the probability of getting at least one $4$ is $\boxed{1 - (5/6)^{4}}$

(c) The probability of getting an odd number on a single dice roll is $1/2$ because there are $3$ desirable outcomes $(1, 3, 5)$ out of $6$ total outcomes. By independence, since we want this outcome to happen four times, the answer is $\boxed{1/2^{4}}$

Answer (score 0):

Since the die is being rolled 4 times, the tool you need is the following rule:
The probability of a set of independent events all happening, is equal to the product of the probabilities of each individual event.
Some version of this statement can probably be found in your textbook.
It means that since no roll of the die affects the outcome of any other roll, we can take the probabilities of getting a certain result on each roll, and multiply them together to get the probability that we’ll get all of the results we’ve specified.

A) the probability of not getting a single 4 then, can be found by multiplying the probability that we don’t get a four in a single roll by itself 4 times. Since the probability of getting a 4 is one in six, the probability of getting something else is five in six, so the answer is given by: 
$$\frac {5}{6}•\frac {5}{6}•\frac {5}{6}•\frac {5}{6}=0.4823$$

B) the probability of  getting at least one 4 is the same as saying the probability that the event in part A won’t happen, so it can be found by computing:
$$1-0.4823=0.5177$$

C) the probability of getting all odds is can be found by multiplying together the probability of getting an odd each time. Since half of the numbers from one to six are odd, this means we get
$$\frac {1}{2}•\frac {1}{2}•\frac {1}{2}•\frac {1}{2}=\frac {1}{16} =0.0625$$